Why is my if statement getting a RunTimeException looking for the password8and256CharValidationError on the second loop
I'm trying to have my automation try every password that will display the requirements for a password. After the first iteration of the loop, it gets stuck looking for the password8And256CharValidationError element when I want it to skip that if and move to the next else if.
This is the exception:

java.lang.RuntimeException: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of Proxy element for: DefaultElementLocator 'By.xpath: //*[contains(text(),'Password must be between 8 and 256')]' (tried for 60 second(s) with 1000 milliseconds interval)

@Step("Verify the create account fields.")
public void getInvalidAccountDetails() {
    try {
        if (!isFirstTime) {
            clickCreateAccount();
        }
        isFirstTime = false;
        fillValidAccountDetails();

        boolean isPasswordErrorHandled = false;

        for (String invalidPassword : invalidPasswords) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            fillPassword(invalidPassword);
            fillConfirmPassword(invalidPassword);
            clickCreateAccountAccountPage();
            if (isElementPresent(password8And256CharValidationError)) {
                verifyPasswordLengthWarning();
                isPasswordErrorHandled = true;
            } else if (isElementPresent(passwordSpecialCharValidationError)) {
                verifyOneSpecialCharacter();
                isPasswordErrorHandled = true;
            } else if (isElementPresent(password1numberValidationError)) {
                verifyOneNumberWarning();
                isPasswordErrorHandled = true;
            } else if (!isPasswordErrorHandled) {
                fillPassword("Test@123");
                fillConfirmPassword("Test@1234");
                clickCreateAccountAccountPage();
                verifyConfirmPasswordNotMatchValidationError();
            }
            clearPasswordFields();
        }
    }
}

I have tried using different catch exceptions but that didn't help.

Some feedback:

Best practice is for each script to only contain a single test. So break out these four scenarios into four separate tests. NOTE: I added a test to cover passwords of less than 8 characters AND more than 256 characters.

Each test should have it's own browser. This gives each test the most likely chance to succeed and not be polluted by other tests that ran before it in the browser. Each test should: 1. start a new browser, 2. complete the steps and do validations, and 3. close the browser.

By having each scenario be it's own test and having it's own browser, you to gain a huge speed increase through parallel execution.

It also makes the test easier to debug, read, and maintain. Right now you've got a bunch of ifs inside a for loop which makes it much harder to tell what you are currently testing.

If an early validation fails, you get no info on the later tests/validations.


I would write the tests like the below. Each one is clearly named, the steps are clear, and any failure is clear. The tests are easy to read and understand, maintenance is easy, and debugging is easy.
NOTE: I don't know your scenarios so you will need to update the different invalid passwords to match the intended scenario but this should give you an idea of a better way to organize the tests.
public void password8And256CharShortValidation() {
    clickCreateAccount();
    fillValidAccountDetails();
    String invalidPassword = "aaaaaa";
    fillPassword(invalidPassword);
    fillConfirmPassword(invalidPassword);
    clickCreateAccountAccountPage();
    verifyPasswordLengthWarning();
}

public void password8And256CharLongValidation() {
    clickCreateAccount();
    fillValidAccountDetails();
    String invalidPassword;
    invalidPassword = "a".repeat(257);
    fillPassword(invalidPassword);
    fillConfirmPassword(invalidPassword);
    clickCreateAccountAccountPage();
    verifyPasswordLengthWarning();
}

public void passwordSpecialCharValidation() {
    clickCreateAccount();
    fillValidAccountDetails();
    String invalidPassword = "aaaaaaa!";
    fillPassword(invalidPassword);
    fillConfirmPassword(invalidPassword);
    clickCreateAccountAccountPage();
    verifyOneSpecialCharacter();
}

public void passwordOneNumberValidation() {
    clickCreateAccount();
    fillValidAccountDetails();
    String invalidPassword = "aaaaaaa1";
    fillPassword(invalidPassword);
    fillConfirmPassword(invalidPassword);
    clickCreateAccountAccountPage();
    verifyOneNumberWarning();
}

public void passwordDoesNotMatchValidation() {
    clickCreateAccount();
    fillValidAccountDetails();
    fillPassword("Test@123");
    fillConfirmPassword("Test@1234");
    clickCreateAccountAccountPage();
    verifyConfirmPasswordNotMatchValidationError();
}

